# Java: How to shuffle 2 ArrayList with same algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, shuffle

I want to shuffle the cardList and valueList with algorithm, but when i use the shuffle collection for each one, they use different algorithm. So when i pull a card it will be a random card from the deck and the same card does not come up again.

```
public class BlackJack {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        Scanner input =new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> cardList= new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> cardShuffle= new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Integer> valueList= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<String> valueShuffle= new ArrayList<String>();

        cardList = card(cardList); 
        valueList = value(valueList);

        Collections.shuffle(cardList);
        Collections.shuffle(valueList);

        System.out.println(cardList);
        System.out.println(valueList);

    }
    private static ArrayList card(ArrayList<String> cardList){
        String cards = null;
        String suits = null;
        int cardCount = 0;
        for(int s = 1;s<5; s++){

            switch (s){
            case 1: suits = " of Heart"; break;
            case 2: suits = " of Diamond"; break;
            case 3: suits = " of Spades"; break;
            case 4: suits = " of Clubs"; break;
            }

            for(int c = 1;c<14; c++){
                switch (c){
                case 1: cards = "2"; break;
                case 2: cards = "3"; break;
                case 3: cards = "4"; break;
                case 4: cards = "5"; break;
                case 5: cards = "6"; break;
                case 6: cards = "7"; break;
                case 7: cards = "8"; break;
                case 8: cards = "9"; break;
                case 9: cards = "10"; break;
                case 10: cards = "Jack"; break;
                case 11: cards = "Queen"; break;
                case 12: cards = "King"; break;
                case 13: cards = "Ace"; break;
                }
                cardList.add(cardCount, cards + suits);
                cardCount++;
            }
        }

        return cardList;
    }
    private static ArrayList<Integer> value(ArrayList<Integer> valueList){

        int v = 2;
        int counter = 1;
        for(int c = 1;c<52; c++){
            if(v > 10){
                v = 10;
            }
            valueList.add(v);
            v++;
            counter++;
            if(counter>13){
                counter = 1;
                v=2;
            }
        }

        return valueList;
    }
}
```

Edit: I made a second class as @Cinnam had suggested, then used a For int to shuffle the cards with a random number.

```
public class BlackJack {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        Scanner input =new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList<String> cardList= Cards.card(); 
        ArrayList<Integer> valueList= Cards.value(); 
        ArrayList<String> cardShuffle= new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Integer> valueShuffle= new ArrayList<Integer>();

        int r = 0;
         for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++){
             r = rand.nextInt(52);
                    cardShuffle.add(i,cardList.get(r));
                    valueShuffle.add(i,valueList.get(r));
             }
        System.out.println(cardShuffle);

}
```

Comment: your cardShuffle and valueShuffle arrays are never being used.

Comment: It looks like you need to create a method that can take in both ArrayLists and shuffle them.. I dont see that in your code. I see two different methods that shuffle two different data sets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best solution in your case is to create a class that will hold both card and value:

```
class ValuedCard {

    private String card;
    private int value;

    // constructor, getters/setters...
}
```

Then you can have just one list `ArrayList<ValuedCard>` and shuffle it.

Comment: Good solution, but I would use enums for value and card type.

Comment: @barak1412 Agreed, I was trying to keep it simple and similar to OP's original code.

Comment: @Cinnam From using your solution, I believe it would keep all card in one place, and overwrite each time its called.

I did use make another class to keep card and value in an array-list, and when called, i can initialize it in the main class.

Comment: @AnjeshShrestha `Collections.shuffle()` will shuffle the elements of the collection, whatever they are. It works the same way for `String`s, `ValuedCard`s or any other objects.

Answer (score 2):

First a couple of answers to you questions:

You could use a map to keep the values mapped to the cards. That way you can look up the value just by sending in a card.

```
Map<String, Integer> cardsWithValues = new HashMap<>();
//Fill it by going cardsWithValue.put("2 of Dimonds", 2) for all cards. You can use a loop.

  //Shuffle the cards array, then you can get the values by doing:
   System.out.print(cardsWithValue.get(cards.get(i));
```

This works, but it's not all that pretty. Another option is just to create a card class.

```
Public class Card{
    Integer value;
    String cardName;
    public Card(Integer value, String cardName){
        this.value = value;
        this.cardName = cardName;
    }
```

Then you can just store the Cards in a list, and everything works. This might be the most Java way of doing it. You can even give the class some utility functions. Maybe you just want to send in a suit and a number instead of the full string.

The last option is to send in a seed to the shuffle method.

```
Long seed = 1234;
Random r = new Random(seed); 
Collections.shuffle(cardsList, r);
r = new Random(seed);
Collections.shuffle(valueList, r);
```

Now over to something else: A comments on your code.

```
private static ArrayList card(ArrayList<String> cardList){
```

You send this method a list that you add everything to, and then you return the list. You don't really don't have to do both. You can either just do

```
    ArrayList<String> cardList= card(); 

 private static ArrayList card(){
        List<String> cardList = new ArrayList<String>
        //Fill it with stuff 
        return cardList;
    }
```

or you could just send in the list and not return it. I would prefer the first method, since it's cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an overloaded version of the [Collections.shuffle()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List,%20java.util.Random)) that accepts a [Random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) as a parameter, which you can initialized using the same seed via the [setSeed()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#setSeed-long-) method.

So in your code you'll need a `Random` per card deck both using the same seed, example:

```
Random rand1 = new Random();
rand1.setSeed(123);

Random rand2 = new Random();
rand2.setSeed(123);

//..and further below

Collections.shuffle(cardList, rand1);
Collections.shuffle(valueList, rand2);
```

Just make sure you shuffle both together (you want better OO design to encapsulate this).

Also be mindful that inside `Collection.shuffle()` *the size of the array is getting used* therefore in your case both of your collections need to have the same size.

In the code example above this is not the case since there is a bug:

In your static `value()` method the for loop needs to be inclusive of 52, in other words:

```
for(int c = 1;c<=52; c++){
```

In this case, the code result is as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Your values and your cards are in 2 separate ArrayLists, so when you shuffle them, they'll be shuiffled differently, and they'll no longer correspond. My suggesation is to create a new class called Card, have a single ArrayList with Cards in it, and shuffle that.

Here's a possible Card class:

```
public class Card {

public static enum Suit {SPADE,HEART,DIAMOND,CLUB};

public static enum Value {

    //The integer parameter is the score. Adjust as needed.
    ACE(1),DEUCE(2),THREE(3),FOUR(4),FIVE(5),SIX(6),SEVEN(7),
    EIGHT(8),NINE(9),TEN(10),JACK(10),QUEEN(10),KING(10);
    int score;
    Value(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    }
}

private Suit suit;
private Value value;

public Card(Suit suit, Value value) {
    this.suit = suit;
    this.value = value;
}

public int getScore() {
    return value.score;
}

}
```

You can create a pack (ArrayList) like this:

```
ArrayList<Card> pack = new ArrayList<Card>();

for (Card.Value value : Card.Value.values()) {
    for (Card.Suit suit : Card.Suit.values()) {
        pack.add(new Card(suit, value));
    }
}

//finally, shuffle it:
Collections.shuffle(pack);
```